# Zip folder generated with corrupted files using NodeJS and archiver

Tags: node.js, backend

I've created a web application that uses one or more building identifiers to generate xlsx files from an AS400 to my back end in NodeJS. These files are stored in a folder at the root of the backend, called "downloads". My problem is that the zip is downloaded with corrupted files, while the files generated are accessible and error-free

Here is my code for the zip download :

```
const download = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log("TRY");
    const immeuble = req.params.immeuble;
    console.log("Immeuble : ", req.params.immeuble);
    const immGenerateArray = immeuble.split(",");

    if (immGenerateArray.length === 1) {
       ...
    } else {
      const zipName = "fichiers_generes.zip";
      const output = fs.createWriteStream(__basedir + "/downloads/" + zipName);
      const archive = archiver("zip", {
        zlib: { level: 9 }, // Niveau de compression maximum
      });

      // Gestionnaire d'événements pour savoir quand l'archive est terminée
      output.on("close", function () {
        console.log(archive.pointer() + " total bytes");
        console.log(
          "Archiver has been finalized and the output file descriptor has closed."
        );
        // Définir les en-têtes pour permettre le téléchargement du fichier zip
        res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", `attachment; filename=${zipName}`);
        res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/zip");

        // Télécharger le fichier zip
        res.download(__basedir + "/downloads/" + zipName, zipName, (err) => {
          if (err) {
            res.status(500).send({
              message: "Impossible de télécharger le fichier. " + err,
            });
          } else {
            console.log("Téléchargement terminé");
            // Supprime le fichier zip une fois qu'il a été téléchargé
            fs.unlinkSync(__basedir + "/downloads/" + zipName);
          }
        });
      });

      output.on("end", function () {
        console.log("Data has been drained");
      });

      // good practice to catch warnings (ie stat failures and other non-blocking errors)
      archive.on("warning", function (err) {
        if (err.code === "ENOENT") {
          // log warning
        } else {
          // throw error
          throw err;
        }
      });

      // good practice to catch this error explicitly
      archive.on("error", function (err) {
        throw err;
      });

      // Lier l'archive au flux de sortie
      archive.pipe(output);

      // Ajouter les fichiers générés à l'archive en utilisant un flux
      immGenerateArray.forEach((immeuble) => {
        const filePath = __basedir + "/downloads/excel_" + immeuble + ".xlsx";
        console.log("filePath : ", filePath);

        if (fs.existsSync(filePath)) {
          console.log(`Le fichier ${filePath} existe.`);

          const readStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
          archive.append(readStream, { name: "excel_" + immeuble + ".xlsx" });
        } else {
          console.log(`Le fichier ${filePath} n'existe pas.`);
        }
      });

      // Finalise l'archive principale
      archive.finalize();
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send({
      message: "Une erreur s'est produite: " + error,
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Try to change the library responsible for compression, and be sure there aren’t no async / await issues. Very strange.